# What is the quickest way to recursively add directories onto the $LOAD_PATH in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to slap everything in vendor/gems/gems/**/lib onto the load path. I've got a way to do it, but it just feels clunky.
Right now, I'm doing it via:

`base = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "..", "vendor", "gems", "gems"))

libs = File.join(base, "**", "lib")

Dir.glob(libs) { |lib| $LOAD_PATH.unshift lib}`

I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Comment: btw. http://refactormycode.com is a great site for these kinds of questions. you might be able to find some alternative ideas there.

Comment: Cool site - I'll have to check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think setting up the base path via `File` is fine. but you don't need to iterate over the list of directories to put them into the `$LOAD_PATH`. you could use `unshift` and expand the array.

```
libs = File.expand_path("../../vendor/gems/**/lib", __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift *Dir.glob(libs)
```

Comment: A bit shorter to just splat the Dir.glob call, yup. Didn't think of that. But ultimately I'm wondering if there's a way to do this without the Dir.glob call at all?

Comment: i don't think there is a much better way. you just have to get every single path and put it into the $LOAD_PATH. that's the problem and using Dir.glob seems to be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was:

```rb
$LOAD_PATH.unshift *Dir.glob(File.join(__dir__, "*", "lib"))
```

e.g.

```rb
>> $LOAD_PATH.unshift *Dir.glob(File.join(__dir__, "*", "lib"))
=> 
["/Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/actioncable/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/actionmailbox/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/actionmailer/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/actionpack/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/actiontext/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/actionview/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activejob/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activemodel/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activestorage/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activesupport/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/railties/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/plugins/ruby/rubygems-plugin",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/reline-0.4.2/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/irb-1.11.1/lib",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/arm64-darwin23",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/3.3.0",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/3.3.0/arm64-darwin23",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0",
 "/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/arm64-darwin23"]
```